# Carousel can't display tables or items? and how to change indicator color

Tags: html, css, carousel, bootstrap-5

I wanted to use bootstrap 5 for displaying the items in a row like a set of 3 to 12 or so and next slide having another 3 or 12 but when i add carousel it shows the items below each other Here is the code i wrote
'''

```
  <div class="row carousel-item active container-fluid">

    <div class="card col-lg-1">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="images/shoes.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Shoes</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-lg-1">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="images/shoes2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Shoes</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-lg-1">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="images/shoes3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Shoes</h3>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row carousel-item container-fluid">

    <div class="card col-lg-1">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="images/watch.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Shoes</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-lg-1">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="images/watch1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Shoes</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card col-lg-1">
      <div class="images">
        <img src="images/watch2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Shoes</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

  <button class="carousel-control-prev" data-bs-target="#image-slider" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" data-bs-target="#image-slider" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>

</div>
```

Help me i don't know how to do this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap everything in a parent div like 
`<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">`
You can change the ID but the classes and data attribute are required. And if you change the ID then make sure to change it in the rest of the carousel code like the buttons

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide bg-dark" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-primary">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-secondary">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-info">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-success">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-warning">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-danger">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-dark">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-light">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-primary">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-secondary">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-info">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-success">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-warning">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-danger">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-dark">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
            <div class="text-bg-light">
              <h5>Title</h5>
              <p>Some quick example text</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Its a bit complex but i understood how it works, can we change the items contain in it according to the size of the window? ex- PC/laptop size like -12 items and tablet size - 6 items and mobile - 3 items? this is the reason i used col-lg-1

Comment: @TonyStark001 I updated the answer to use `col-4 col-md-2 col-lg-1` which will give 3 items per row on mobile, 6 items per row on tablet, and 12 items per row on desktop

Comment: Thank you it kind of worked, do i need to use java script for changing the carousel items limit like when tablet sized 6 elements in 1 slide and 3 elements in 1 slide i'm gonna brain storm for that logic. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @TonyStark001 oh, I understand what you want now!! Yeah you will need JavaScript for this, I can recommend SwiperJS as a library, it's amazing https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view and you can control the slides per view per breakpoint https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-breakpoints -- if you feel confident with JS then you can maybe adapt the Bootstrap carousel